# version 8.0 SC: ParserError: Expected '(' but got ')'

Tags: solidity-0.8.x

Following is my SC:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;
contract DS{
   address payable cer;
   address public owner;
   constructor() public {
      owner = msg.sender;
      cer = (payable) msg.sender;
   }   
}
```

The error message is:

> ParserError: Expected '(' but got ')'
> --> contracts/DoS1_DoS2.sol:9:21: | 9 | cer = (payable) msg.sender; | ^

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your syntax for type-casting is wrong.
the correct syntax for this is: `cer = payable(msg.sender);`